# Can a subclass of B (which inherits from class A) inherit from a subclass of A instead of A itself?

Tags: ios, oop

I'm working on an accessibility project for an iOS application. Because accessibility does not act quite as advertised, I have to override `accessibilityFrame`, `accessibilityActivationPoint` and `pointInside:withEvent` in a subclass in order to expand the region recognized by VoiceOver (for both drawing and touch recognition) beyond the "natural" bounds of the control view. So, in order to change the VoiceOver bounds of a `UIButton` I have to subclass that class and then add these three methods. In order to do this for a `UILabel` I have to add another subclass with the code, and so on.

I can refactor the code in these methods to a central location, but I was wondering if this can be done more elegantly with inheritance. I'd like to put this code into a subclass of `UIView` (maybe called `UIViewAccessible`) and then create a subclass of `UIButton` called `UIButtonAccessible` which inherits from `UIButton` which would in turn inherit from `UIViewAccessible` instead of `UIView`. Is this possible, or can something like this be done with a category?

**Edit:** According to the docs, you can't really achieve this with a category:

> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime.

Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: This can't be done as you describe because Objective-c doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: Maybe use method swizzling and/or categories to override the framework implementations with your own?

Comment: Hmm, I don't use categories much, but I've always perceived them as a way of adding new methods to an existing (probably sealed) class. I didn't realize they could also override existing methods on a class, if indeed they can. If that is the case, then I think my task may be ridiculously easy, as I can just add these three methods to a `UIView` category, and then I won't even have to subclass anything else.

Comment: Looks like categories won't work for this, as it's undefined which implementation of a same-named method is used.

Comment: That's only if there are two categories defining a method with the same name. If that's the case then you'll need to swizzle or find another workaround. Also perhaps you can file a bug report with Apple, they seem to take accessibility really seriously they may have a workaround for you or make an improvement.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: are you sure ("That's only if there are two categories defining a method with the same name")? In the sentence I posted, two categories with a same-named method is only one of the cases this applies to, the other case being a category with a same-named method as the original class.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: Apple does seem to take accessibility seriously, but that doesn't mean they're doing a good job of it. The accessibility stuff does a decent job with a plain, straightforward UI, but if your UI has any unusual custom elements (especially ones that make heavy use of swiping gestures) you're in for some pain.

Comment: Another problem with categories is that if you want to override the method, there's no way to call its super implementation.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no, it can't, since your `UIViewAccessible` is a second degree sibling to `UIButton` in the inheritance chain (both inherit from `UIView` at some point). But I guess you already knew that. As for a solution, you could wrap around your `UIView` accessible classes a decorator and use protocols for strong typing. That way you'll keep the code in one place. I've described this technique [here](http://cocoaexposed.com/post/40353790996/advanced-delegation-decorator-pattern) in more detail (although for a different purpose, it's the same situation).

For the views that would support accessibility you'll have to do this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView<MyAccesibilityProtocol>* view;

//self.view can come from the nib or previously created in code
self.view = [[AccesibilityDecorator alloc] initWithDecoratedObject:self.view];

//you can then use self.view like any other UIView, 
//and because it also implements an 
//accessibility protocol, you can use the methods 
//implemented in the wrapper as well.
//more than that, you can control which methods to override
//in the AccesibilityDecorator class
[self.view addSubview:otherView];//could be overridden or not
[self.view myAccesibilityMethod];//custom method declared in the protocol
```